# 生成したURLをデータベースに格納したい。

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

home.phpのタブ１に表示されている画像群から１つクリックし、
***a.php、***b.phpと進んで行き、最終的に、
はじめに選択した画像URLにパラメータが付加されたURL（$p_url = "http://*******"）が完成します。

そのURLをデータベースに格納してゆき、home.phpのタブ２に一覧で取得・表示したいのですが、
phpMyAdminで見ても、レコードが追加されている様子がありません。
以下のようにして、データを取り出せているとして、どうやって表示すればいいかわかりません......。

データベースを使わず、生成したURLをphp上にストックしていく方法など、無いですよね？
もしありましたら、そちらでも構いません。
foreachで、生成したURLが存在するだけ 繰り返し吐き出したいのですが。。

よろしくお願い致します。

[PHPとMySQLを使って、初めてのDB接続](http://liginc.co.jp/designer/archives/119) こちらを参考にしました。

＜***b.php＞

```
//DBへ接続
$db = mysql_connect("mysql999.db.sakura.ne.jp","ID","password");
if(!$db){
    die("DBに接続できませんでした");
}
//DBの選択
$conn = mysql_select_db("db_name",$db);
if(!$conn){
    die("DBに接続できませんでした");
}
//SQL文を変数に格納
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'db_name'.'p***URLs'('url') VALUES({$p_url});";
//SQL文の実行
mysql_query($sql);
```

＜home.php タブ２＞

```
//DBからデータを取得して格納
$get_sql = "SELECT * FROM 'p***URLs' WHERE 'url' = $get_id";
$res = mysql_query($get_sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

※p***URLsはテーブル名、urlはフィールド名。
※データベースはさくらインターネットのものを使用しています。
※home.phpのタブはjavascriptで作成しています。

Comment: 私の勉強不足で、MySQLのことがよくわかっていないのですが、
(http://www.phpbook.jp/tutorial/mysql/) こちらに沿ってやればできるのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考にしているサイトが古いのと誤解を招く書き方をしてるので、いろいろまずいコードになってます。

PHP+MySQLの解説をしてるサイトのほとんどは古いか間違っているかその両方なので、なかなかここを参考にしたら間違いが無い、というのを知りません。

とりあえずサンプルを書いてみました。(SQLに突っ込むパラメータがどういう由来かわからないので唐突に登場させていますので、このままでは動きません)

```
<?php
try{
    $hostname = 'hostname';
    $dbname   = 'dbname';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    //DBへの接続 文字コードの指定を必ずする
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

    //お約束
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //INSERTを準備して･･･
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO p***URLs (url) values (:url)");
    if(!$stmt)
    {
        $error_info = $dbh->errorInfo();
        die($error_info[2]);
    }

    //値を割り当てて･･･
    $stmt->bindValue(":url", $p_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    //実行
    $stmt->execute();

    //SELECT
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM p***URLs WHERE url = :url");
    if(!$stmt)
    {
        $error_info = $dbh->errorInfo();
        die($error_info[2]);
    }
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt->bindValue(":url", $get_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $row["url"];
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

参考にしてはいけないサイトを見分けるポイントを載せておきます。

- mysql_connectなどmysql_*系の関数は古いものなので使ってはいけません。これが載っていると言うことは情報が古いので参考になりません。mysqli_*か上記のPDOならよいです。
- 文字コードを指定している部分(上記のサンプルであれば、`new PDO`のパラメータで指定しています)があるかどうか。無ければダメです。
- PDOの場合、`setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)`が無い
- SQLを組み立てるのに、`"SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '" . $var . "'"` `"SELECT * FROM name = ${var}"`などのように変数を連結している。
- バインド機構について説明がない

バインド機構というのは、

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM p***URLs WHERE url = :url");
$stmt->bindValue(":url", $get_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

こんな風に、SQL中には「プレースホルダ」という目印を置いて、後でそれに値を割り当てる(bindする)方法のことです。プレースホルダは`:url`のような名前の場合と`?`記号を使うときがあります。

なぜこういう注意が必要かについては、IPAが公開している[「安全なウェブサイトの作り方」と「安全なSQLの呼び出し方」](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/vuln/websecurity.html)、書籍ですが「体系的に学ぶ 安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方」(ISBN: 978-4-7973-6119-3)を読んでみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！たしかに2008年の記事ですもんね…。今 試せる環境にないので、明日か明後日になるかもしれませんが、必ずまた返信いたします！せっかくなのにごめんなさい、ありがとうございます。（SQLに突っ込むパラメータ、というのは、$p_urlでよろしいでしょうか。こちらは、ドメイン＋php+InstagramAPIからの画像等＋それを加工するjsの値opacityなどに由来するURLです）

Comment: suzukisさま、ご師事いただいたコードを試しました。見事データベースに格納された！のですが、私の力では取り出すことができませんでした...。
**「格納するページ」と「取得するページ」にコードを分割すると、どのようになるでしょうか？**
頂いたコードでも、自分で分割してみたコードでも、やってみたのですが、どちらも`echo $row["url"];`されませんでした。
最終的にはデータベースから取得したURLを、iframeタグのsrcにしたいです。

参考にしてはいけないサイトの指南も、ありがとうございました。今後の学習に役立てます。

Comment: あえて言いますが、これだけ短いコードで何をやってるか分からない、デバッグ手法もわからない、というのは明らかに自分のレベル以上の所に手を出している証拠です。また、大いに誤解されているのですがPHPは決して初心者向きの言語ではありません。とりあえずPHPとDBのことは忘れて、RubyかPythonあたりで'Hello, world'から一歩一歩勉強された方がいいでしょう。

Comment: レコードを取り出せなかった、というよりは表示できなかった原因は、`echo $row["url"];`に`htmlspecialchars()`が足りなかっただけでした。今は事情により実践の中で勉強しているもので、問題に突き当たることが多いので、今後改めて基礎的な部分を勉強したいと思います。ありがとうございました。