# PHP PDOでMySQLのデータを削除したい

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

私はいまPHP PDOを使い、content.phpに削除処理を実装しようとしています。
以下のコードでは、「//取得」のところで表示されている画像A(src=$xxurl)を、*content.php内では*削除（？）できます（、というか非表示になります）。

しかし、サムネイル一覧ページである*home.php*に進むと、削除されておらず、画像Aのサムネイルをクリックしcontent.phpに遷移すると、画像Aは再表示されてしまいます。
phpMyAdminでデータを確認しても、削除できていません。

content.php上のボタンをクリックすると、home.phpに遷移し、そこのサムネイル一覧とデータベースから、（ひとつの）データを削除する方法を教えていただきたいです。

【content.php】

```
try{
$hostname = 'mysql321.db.sakura.ne.jp';
$dbname   = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'xxxxx';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password
                , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO xxxxURLs (name, url, time) values (:name, :url, :time)");
if(!$stmt)
{
    $error_info = $dbh->errorInfo();
    die($error_info[2]);
}

$stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(":url", $xxurl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$today = date("M d Y Ah:i");
$stmt->bindValue(":time", $today, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

//取得
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT time FROM xxxxURLs WHERE url = :url");
$stmt->bindValue(":url", $xxurl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<div class=\"text\">";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $theday = htmlspecialchars($row["time"]);
    echo $theday;
}
echo "</div>";

//削除
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"home.php\"><button type='submit' name='action' value='delete'></form>";
if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM xxxxURLs WHERE url = :url LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindValue(":url", $xxurl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

【home.php】

```
<?php
try{
$hostname = 'mysql321.db.sakura.ne.jp';
$dbname   = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'xxxxx';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password
                , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

//取得
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url FROM pastaURLs WHERE name = :name");
  $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<div>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $album = htmlspecialchars($row["url"]);
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<a href=\"{$album}\"></a>";
    echo "<iframe src=\"{$album}\"></iframe></div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ぱっと見ですが、content.phpで

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"home.php\"><button type='submit' name='action' value='delete'></form>";
```

になっていますので、このボタンを押した時にはhome.phpに遷移します。削除のロジックはcontent.phpにあるので削除はされないでしょう。

全体を追いかけたわけではないので、それ以外にも間違ってるところはあるかもしれません。

---

動作とは(困ったことに)直接関係ないのですが、少なくとも

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password
                , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

はまずいことが起きるので、[前回提示したサンプル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/18868/5793)のとおり、

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
```

にしてください。

Comment: suzukisさま ありがとうございます。home.phpに遷移させるために`action=\"home.php\"`を追加したのでした...。確かにこれを削除したらデータもDeleteされました。まだまだ未熟者です。別の方法で同時に遷移させたいと思います。
文字コードの指定についてですが、私の環境(php5.2)の都合上、こうするほかないかなと...。安全な方法で日本語を文字化けさせない方法をご存知でしたらお教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: @rrrnnnn PHP5.2は遙か昔にメンテナンスが終了していますので、メンテナンスが継続しているバージョンに更新することをおすすめします。

Comment: 私だけのサーバでないので、なかなか事情が難しいのです...。

Comment: @rrrnnnn そのように制限がある環境なのであれば、その管理者の方に「その環境における適切な作法」を指示してもらってください。